# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element '…'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

My XSD is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="AppRegisterConfig">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="restServiceUrl" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="timeout" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="attempts" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

My XML is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appregister-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="appregister-config.xsd">

  <restServiceUrl><url>url 1</url></restServiceUrl>
  <timeout>15000</timeout>
  <attempts>5</attempts>  
</appregister-config>
```

Any idea what I may have missed?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said how you invoked the validation, but by default the schema processor will look in the schema for an element declaration that matches the outermost element name in your source document, and if it can't find one, it will tell you so. That's what's happening here.

I would expect to see

```
<xs:element name="appregister-config" type="AppRegisterConfig"/>
```

in your schema.

Comment: I tried this. I am getting following error now :   
       - Start tag of element <xs:complexType>
 - s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'type' cannot appear in element 'complexType'.  
It is showing this error before invoking it.

Comment: Well it's telling you there is an xs:complexType element with a 'type' attribute. Is there?

Comment: I mean I put the line you suggested and it gave me new error. yes there is element of complexType which consists of another set of elements. My corresponding class is having methods to fetch these elements. But my xml is not agreeing with the xsd. Please help.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't answer my questions.